# Workflow Designer support for MS Visio 2016

Tags: workflow, web8, visio-designer

I am working with SDL Web 8, and want to install the Workflow Designer. According to the documentation this needs Visio 2010 SP2 or Visio 2013. These are no longer shipped by Microsoft. Are there plans to support Visio 2016 any time soon?

Short of that, does anyone have the trial installer for a compatible 2013 or 2010 version?

Comment: Worth noting that Visio 2016 (32-bit) is [supported](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-3C6BD51E-0EA5-4375-A62C-76855A5B242F) for SDL Web 8.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Onno mentioned, the support of Visio 2016 is currently in our backlog. We have already done some testing and did not found any issues from Content Manager prospective. There is so far only one issue with installer (it does not properly detect that Visio 2016 is installed, so fails on pre-requisites check). But there is a workaround:

1. On Web8 cd-layout navigate to folder with Visio Workflow Designer installation folder and find "Install SDL Web Visio Workflow Designer Client.lnk" shortcut.
2. Right click on it and go to its Properties.
3. Open Shortcut tab
4. Add " Visio=2016" at the end of Target string.
5. Apply changes and Run SDL Web Visio Workflow Designer Client.lnk

Given that you can use Workflow Designer with the latest Visio version, but just keep in mind that it is not officially supported yet. Keep in mind that we support only 32-bit version of Visio.

Answer (score 3):

Support for Microsoft Visio 2016 is planned for Q1.

Comment: did this get added to the latest release?